# Does this double integral give area or volume?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, area, volume

I've encountered a question like this: $$\int_{-1}^0 \int_0^{-1}x y\ dy \ dx.$$ I think it represents the volume of some solid object in the 3rd quadrant and the value of f(x,y) is always positive as both the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate are negative and their product will always be positive. So we can assume that the volume of the solid is along the positive z-axis, so positive volume. Then why is the answer -0.25, which is negative?

Comment: **Note**: If $f(x,y)\ge 0$, then the volume $V$ of the solid  $S$, which lies above $R$ in the $xy$-plane and under the graph of $f$, is the double integral of the function $f(x,y)$ over the rectangle $R$.

Comment: yeah upon solving the volume is coming out to be -0.25, but when I imagine it geometrically the volume seems to be positive

Comment: To @Sarvani: $\int_a^b = -\int_b^a$

Comment: An integral only gives "area under the curve" when it is set up in the particular way that gives area under the curve. One condition is that you must integrate in the positive direction. If you integrate in the negative direction, the process is reversed, and you **take away** the area under the curve instead of adding it. It's just the way this kind of integral is defined. There are other kinds of integral that work differently, but they use different notation.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is indeed computing a volume between the function values of the integrand $xy$ in a domain bounded by the integral boundaries.

The value is negative, due to the "direction" you are integrating over the $y$-axis. Flip it and you get the same answer with a positive sign:

$$\int_{-1}^0 \int_{-1}^0x y\ dy \ dx.$$

---

Edit:

The sign of the value of the integral is related to the integration direction, due to the rules of integration you are applying. In this specific case, we can compute a simpler integral of the function $f(x)=x$ step by step, to observe this.
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^1 x dx &= \left. \frac{x^2}{2} \right|_0^1=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{0}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\\
\int_{1}^0 x dx &= \left. \frac{x^2}{2} \right|_1^0=\frac{0}{2}-\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}$$

You see, the function we integrate doesn change, only the direction, which flips the sign of the answer.

If you, however, are interested in the area $A[f]$ under the curve of the function, then you should apply the absolute value:

$$A[f] = \left\vert \int_{a}^b x dx \right\vert = ...$$

This result will always be positive, as we would expect from an area (or volume).

Comment: i dont undertand why the sign of the answer is related to the direction I integrate over the y-axis.

Comment: like through any way, the multiplication is gonna be positive right? but why is the sign changing,im confused...

Comment: I have added an explanation for this question to my answer above. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you! but in the example you gave

1)∫10xdx it is like you are going from 0 to 1 on the x-axis and plotting x-values on the y-axis and it results an upright triangle in the 1st quadrant

2)∫01xdx it is like you are going from 1 to 0 on the x-axis and plotting x-values on y-axis and it DOESNT give an inverted triangle in the 4th quadrant(that has an area of -0.5), but it also gives the same kind of triangle and that too of the same direction

so then why are their signs negotiating when you reverse the limits?

Comment: My advice is the following: Stop thinking about which function you are integrating, and how they look like geometrically for a moment. Just read the second part of my answer and observe, that a change of the integral boundaries flips the sign of the result. Just try to get comfortable with this idea. It is simply a result of how integrating such simple functions works. This is the simplest explanation why your double integral is negative.

Comment: The volume or area that you want to find, is of course always the absolute value of your integration result (=the "positive value"). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the double integral like this:

Visualise a 3-D plot of the function $f(x, y) = xy$ on $\mathbb R^3$. It should look somewhat like this:
[image]

(you can use [this link](https://www.desmos.com/3d) if you want to try it out yourself)

 Consider an infinitesimally small piece, called $A_0$, of the X-Y plane of area $dA = dx \cdot dy$. Then, the SIGNED volume under the curve over that small piece of area will be $dV = \displaystyle \int\int_{A_0}xy\ dx\ dy$. Summing the little volumes up, taking areas which span from the given limits of x and y, will give us the required sums of SIGNED volumes,  $\displaystyle \int_{y_i}^{y_f}\int_{x_i}^{x_f}xy\ dx\ dy$.

NOTE: The signed volume means that if the curve is under the XY plane, i.e. $f(x, y) < 0$, then $dV < 0$. The direction in which you integrate matters, as you can see because the function seems positive on $[-1, 0]\times[-1,0]$. But the conventional direction of increment is in the right and upward directions, which have been flipped in the question, thus making the integral negative.

Comment: so the problem doesn't represent volume? the graph looks like it is computing area

Comment: Not really, in the physical sense. If you wanted the physical volume, i.e. how much sand you could fit into the curve, then you'd have to take $$\int\int |xy|\ dx\ dy.$$

Comment: so is it calculating area or volume?I've seen this type of syntax and it always gave me volume, but when there is 1 instead of xy it gave the area

Comment: Yeah, numerically replacing xy with 1 will give you the area. However, visualise it like this: Imagine a plane just above the X-axis, exactly 1 unit of height above the XY plane, and the double integral would represent the volume under this plane between the given limits of area. This would be numerically equal to the area because the height is constant and equal to 1, so Volume = Area * constant_height = Area * 1 = Area. So the conclusion is: you get the volume, but it is numerically equal to the area.

Comment: Note that the integrand represents the height of the curve at a given point (x, y).

Comment: yeah, and the height is positive regardless of which direction we approach

Comment: yes, but for simplicity, in the 1-variable case, note that when you write $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)dx$ you are essentially taking the limit, as n grows without bound, of the sum $$\sum_i f(x_i)(\Delta x) = \sum_{x_0 = a}^{x_n = b} f(x_i)(x_{i+1} -  x_i)$$ where the interval $[a, b]$ is divided into $n$ regions and $x_{i+1}$ is closer to $b$ than $x_i$ is. When you reverse the direction of integration, then $x_{i+1}$ is closer to $a$ than $x_i$ is. Do you see why the integral becomes negative now?